# Check if a string has more than 1 space between each word and return negative if so

Tags: php, string, space

I have the following string:

```
$name = "John  Lucas";
```

And I'd like to make a condition if `$name` has more than 1 space between each word then return **false**.

Any ideas of how to do that?

**UPDATE EXAMPLE:**

```
<input name="name" type="text"/> //example
<?php
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    if ( $name has more than 2 spaces between each word ) {
        echo 'FALSE';
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$spaceCount = substr_count($name, ' ');`

Comment: hi @MarkBaker, what exactly does this do? Counts all the spaces inside the string? Because I need to verify if the string has more than 1 space between each word

Comment: am curious to know why extra space is an issue; is there a particular reason?

Comment: It counts the number of occurrences of the specified character (a space in this case) in the string, as explained in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Comment: I'm not exactly trying to count the amount of spaces, but if there is more than 1 space between each word in the string `name`, check the **update**

Comment: *"Check if a string has more than 1 space"* - Um... I don't get your comment above here ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- forgive me, that was my mistake, I just updated the title

Comment: @VictorYugo I see. Well, Riggs had popped in an answer based on your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41794894/1 and the edit(s) thereafter made all the difference. Others may have posted more answers based on that (the original) and you'd be surprised as to what others do based on edits done "after the fact"; they downvote answers and some stand on not being "happy campers". Just a quick "FYI" for future questions and to keep the question "clear as crystal" right off the bat ;-) Glad to see you found your solution, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if $name has more than 1 space between each word then return false.

The solution using `preg_match` function:

```
function hasSingleSpaces($str) {
    return (bool) !preg_match("/\w+\s{2,}(?=\w+)/", $str);
}

var_dump(hasSingleSpaces("John     Lucas"));    // false
var_dump(hasSingleSpaces("John Lucas  hello")); // false
var_dump(hasSingleSpaces("John Lucas hello"));  // true
```